# Create or add a collection in marklogic using java client api

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-8

Can we create a new collection in the marklogic using the java client api? As i want my application to create the collection on the startup.

I know I can delete a collection using the Querymanager.newDeleteDefinition and then pass in the definition options.

Comment: Do you know how to add a document with a collection in the metadata?  That's what you need here.

Answer (score 5):

A collection isn't really "created" - it exists when you insert a document and specify the name of a collection to add the document to. It's very much like a tag. A collection then only exists in the sense that there are one or more documents in it.

Why do you need your application to "create" the collection on startup? Even if no documents are added to a collection, you can still query on it and ask questions like how many documents are in it (the answer of course will be zero, until you add a document to it).

Comment: For completeness, while collections are typically implicit, protected collections are defined explicitly. See the [Collections chapter of the Search Developer's Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/collections#chapter) for more info. That said, regular, non-protected collections are usually what's needed, as @rjrudin says. I wouldn't use protected collections unless there was a compelling reason to.